# How can one avoid issues using non-primitive static class variables in c++?

Tags: c++

I've read quite a bit about initialization of static class variables in c++ and while the google coding standard says only create statics of plain old data (i.e., primitives & pointers), I see quite a few examples online and in books where the authors violate that guideline.

I've also read that as long as you keep the statics in a single compilation unit, that you're less likely to encounter undefined initialization problems.

ok...so having said that...I want some expert opinions on whether or not I will encounter some problems down the road with code that looks like...

```
//header file snippet
struct TheStruct {
    string theString;
    string theString2;
    float theFloat;
};

class TheClass {
public:
    static const TheStruct Dude;
    static const TheStruct Blah;
    static const TheStruct TheStructArray[];

    TheClass();
    virtual ~TheClass();
    TheStruct getCurrent();
private:
    TheStruct current;
}

//impl file snippet
const TheStruct TheClass::Dude = { "Dude", "Dude", 0 };
const TheStruct TheClass::Blah = { "Blah", "Blah", 0 };
const TheStruct TheClass::TheStructArray[] = {TheClass::Dude, TheClass::Blah};

TheClass::TheClass() : current(TheClass::Dude) {}
TheClass::~TheClass() {}
TheStruct TheClass::getCurrent() {return current;}
```

I think the `getCurrent()` method is ok.  The static const `Dude` and `Blah` are wrapped in a static array `TheStructArray` that something down the road will use.  But, I'm guessing I'm still gonna have the problem with the array if it is used by some other class?  For instance, the array may be used by the GUI to present valid options to choose from.

I come from a Java background, so I have frequently used `private static final` to define some valid "state"...

Thanks!

Comment: Don't look to the Google coding standards as a guide to good programming practices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//impl file snippet
const TheStruct TheClass::Dude = { "Dude", "Dude", 0 };
const TheStruct TheClass::Blah = { "Blah", "Blah", 0 };
const TheStruct TheClass::TheStructArray[] = {TheClass::Dude, TheClass::Blah};
```

As long as these three lines are written in that order, there is no problem with your code, as they're initialized in the order as mentioned, and so you don't face  [static initialization order fiasco](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14). Otherwise, you should go through [this link](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.14) to read about what problems you might face, and what [solution](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/ctors.html#faq-10.15) you must provide.

Answer (score 1):

Its possible you **might** have problems with

```
TheClass::TheClass() : current(TheClass::Dude) {}
```

IF and only if you have a static or global TheClass declared in a different cpp in your code.  For example:

```
// somewhereelse.h
#include "TheClass.h"

class OtherClass {
  static TheClass myTheClass;
  }

// somewhereelse.cpp
TheClass OtherClass::myTheClass;
```

Initializing the "OtherClass::myTheClass" object (which calls the constructor and accessed TheClass::Dude) might occur before TheClass::Dude has had its values initialized.  Thus you might get random garbage (or worse crash) in the constructor of OtherClass::myTheClass.

This could be avoided somewhat by using the c++ singleton pattern of varied complexity (depending on your requirements) like so.

```
struct TheStruct {
  string theString;
  string theString2;
  float theFloat;
};

class TheClass {
public:
    static const TheStruct &Dude();
    static const TheStruct &Blah();
    static const TheStruct *TheStructArray();

    TheClass();
    virtual ~TheClass();
    TheStruct getCurrent();
private:
    TheStruct current;
};

//impl file snippet
const TheStruct &TheClass::Dude() {
  static TheStruct DudeStruct = { "Dude", "Dude", 0 };
  return DudeStruct;
  }

const TheStruct &TheClass::Blah() {
  static TheStruct BlahStruct = { "Blah", "Blah", 0 };
  return BlahStruct;
  }

const TheStruct *TheClass::TheStructArray() {
  static TheStruct singletonStructArray[] = {TheClass::Dude(), TheClass::Blah()};
  return singletonStructArray;
  }

TheClass::TheClass() : current(TheClass::Dude()) {}
TheClass::~TheClass() {}
TheStruct TheClass::getCurrent() {return current;}
```

Now, no matter how TheClass is used elsewhere, initialization will not be undefined.  If OtherClass has a static TheClass object, even if its initialized before anything else, the DudeStruct will get initialized in time for the copy constructor of "current".

Comment: @Nim thats true and as I stated, the singleton pattern has many forms depending on the use or need.  I was attempting to solve the initialization problem not a thread safety problem.